# Find matching input and returning the matching input and also the unmatching input

Tags: c++, regex

I'm am looping through keyboard input to find a match such as: `int A = 89;`.
Then return the input as tokens like:
`int`, `A`, `=`, `89`, `;`.

I have already tried looping through the input and using regex_match to check the tokens.

```
if (ch == ' ') {
        while (ch == ' ') {
            cin.get(ch);
        }
    }

    while (ch != ' ') {
        token += ch;
        cin.get(ch);
    }

    if (regex_match(token, regex("= | ; | int | float | A | B | C | D | E | [0-9]+ | [0-9]+\.[0-9]+"))){
        return token;
    }
    else {
        return token + ": Error: Unrecognizable token";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the spaces in the regex string and it should work:

```
if (regex_match(token, regex("=|;|int|float|A|B|C|D|E|[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"))) {
    return token;
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Now I just need it to capture a number followed by a semicolon such as: 9;.